# How to localize static resources in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid

I learned how to localize the pages and their dynamic content elements using the L parameter. But how do I localize things like button texts etc? What are the best practices?

For example I have a textual button "toggle menu" which I need to localize. Another example could be footer copyright information text.

EDIT: I have discovered a nicely looking helper

```
<f:translate key="key1" />
```

, but the use is a bit complicated and I cannot seem to make it work. Can someone explain the process? Also I have found some XLIFF reference.

EDIT: Ok, I am able to use the locallang.xml with the translate viewhelper. What is missing from posting it as an answer is that I have to specify the path like

```
<f:translate key="LLL:fileadmin/.../locallang.xml:button-label" />
```

instead of just

```
<f:translate key="key1" />
```

I am not in any extension so I am wondering if there is any location to place the locallang file to, so only the key can be used. extension_name/Resources/Private/Language/ is said to be the right place for extensions. fileadmin/Resources/Private/Language/ does not work, nor does /Resources/Private/Language/.

Comment: I added some instances.

Comment: Typo3 6.1, Fluid (+ vhs ViewHelpers).

Comment: In general you should declare these texts in TypoScript as a cObjects too, so you'll be able to switch it with `GP:L` condition as well, unfortunatelly can't give you any sample atm

Comment: That is unfortunate as I am trying to avoid TypoScript as possible (for instance I create menus via Fluid). Nonetheless I would be grateful for a sample later.

Answer (score 2):

To localize static TypoScript objects, you should not use conditions because they are more costly performance-wise (and you obviously need more code as you see in Urs' example). Better use the lang property:

```
myLabel = TEXT
myLabel.value = Print
myLabel.lang.de = Drucken
```

Link to documentation: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap-lang

Comment: Ah, haven't met that yet. I always used _LOCAL_LANG, but ran into trouble sometimes. Where's that documented, and does it work with insertData as well?

Comment: AFAIK this is only for static values. I added the link to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Heres's the oldschool approach for an actual sample, it works perfectly and reliably:

```
temp.pagetitle = TEXT
temp.pagetitle {
    value = {page:title} (Standard Text)
    insertData = 1
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
temp.pagetitle.value = {page:title} (Translated Text)
[global]
```

or even

constants:

```
thetext = Standard Text
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
thetext = Translated Text
[global]
```

setup:

```
temp.pagetitle = TEXT
temp.pagetitle {
    value = {page:title} {$thetext}
    insertData = 1
}
```